# Background image max size - Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have a row in Bootstrap 3 which holds 2 columns.

On a "desktop" the logo is a small 3 column width and the navigation is the remaining 8 cols in width

+----------------+----------------------------------+
|    My Logo        |                  My Navigation                     |
|                                   |                                                                     |
+----------------+----------------------------------+

My logo is a background image and has some CSS to scale it to the space available (the width and height of the div).

## My Problem

On smaller viewports, I make both the logo and navigation 100% or 12 columns. IE stack vertically with the logo on top and the nav bar undearneath.

+--------------------------+
|         My Logo           
| 
+--------------------------+
|     
My Navigation      |
+--------------------------+

However, once that layout kicks in, my logo is massive and cropped.
I have the logo DIV set to a max height of 150px but the logo background is scaling the full width available and cropping in a letterbox. I'd rather it took up the max height available to it (150px) and defined it's width proportionally based on that.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your time.

```
logo-wrapper {
background-image: url(../../../images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 150px;

background-size: 100%;
background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible what bootstrap's css rule `img{height: auto}` override yours?

Comment: can you post the related HTML too?

Comment: use 
background-size: cover; width: 80%; height: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Setting `background-size: cover` should resolve your problem.
Check the [background-size documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).